# Neural Network basic understanding and visualisation

Tags: python, neural-network, visualization

i am working with a book that is describing neural networks from the very beginning and even without using the numpy functions to multiply vectors etc.

So I have the following code:

```
weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0]

def w_sum(a, b):            # weighted sum function
    assert(len(a) == len(b))
    output = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        output += (a[i] * b[i])
    return output

def neural_network(input, weights):
    pred = w_sum(input, weights)     #the weighted sum function with values = dot product
    return pred



info1 = [8.5, 9.5, 9.9, 9.0]
info2 = [0.65, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9]
info3 = [1.2, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0]

input = [info1[0], info2[0], info3[0]]
pred = neural_network(input, weights)

print(pred)
```

So for this code I also have the following diagram:
[neural network basic structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aL3k.jpg)

Now: What is the network putting into these three knots on the right side of that diagram? To me it seems like the output is the same number (in this case, because I am using `input = [info1[0], info2[0], info3[0]]` the number is: 0.98)
?

Why this diagram? It is given in the book. But what is actually happening, if it all outputs the same number (the weighted sum what equals to 0.85 + 0.13 + 0.0 = 0.98)

I mean I try to understand what this diagram wants to tell me or how I can read it.

I would like to know more about how that w_sum(a, b) function actually operates. I don't understand the structure of what is happening, especially what the assert function is doing.

EDIT: so after the enlightening answers I updated the diagram, how it actually should look regarding the code.

[image: This is the Diagram that fits the code]

Thanks a lot and best wishes

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram (almost) describes the general structure of a Fully Connected Neural Network (it's missing the activation function).

> What is the network putting into these three knots on the right side of that diagram?

Numbers. Information that is derived from the previous layer. What these numbers **actually** mean, and how the network process information, on an intuitive level, is a far more difficult question, for which you rarely get an answer (some CNNs have been broken down to show how images are being transformed through the network and what kind of features each layer extracts). It will be a lot better for you if you only try to understand how the network works, on an operation level (i.e. what mathematical operations happen in each layer), rather than why it works.

As for the implementation, the function `w_sum()` calculates the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors (lists), `a` and `b`. It's implementation is based on the mathematical definition of the dot product.
Also, for the dot product to be defined, the vectors need to have an equal number of components (dimensions). To guarantee that, an `assert` statement is used first. If you are not familiar on what it does, read up on it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/assert-statement).

The confusing bit here is that the implementation does not fully reflect the diagram. For this implementation, the correct diagram would only have one node (the first) on the second layer.

As a final note, the lists `info0`,`info1`, `info2` hold the values for the nodes in the first layer, at time `i`. So, at time 0, the input vector (the values of all nodes in the first layer) is `[info1[0], info2[0], info3[0]]`, at time 1 it is `[info1[1], info2[1], info3[1]]`, etc.

Comment: right, that thing with the diagram was the thing I found confusing too.... so It actually outputs only one node instead of three. Because the three nodes would have the same value of 0.98

Comment: since you only have 3 weights and 3 inputs, you can only define 1 output node. For the 3 nodes to have the same value (0.98), you would need 9 weights (2 more copies of the weight vector you already have).

Comment: Okay. I added a fitting diagram of what this code and THIS Network is doing and outputting in the current state with ```[info1[0], info2[0], info3[0]]``` Now the question: if I would like to know, how to advance the code, that it actually is doing what the first diagram is showing (three output nodes), what do you think it is better to open a new topic?

Comment: It is indeed a new topic, but you should try to figure it out yourself first. Adding more output nodes means having more weights (so your weights could be a list of lists or a matrix if you want to take it a step further) and running the current "algorithm" for every output node.

Comment: okay thanks for that answers, i updated the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668780/basic-neural-network-without-numpy-understanding-the-iteration-steps

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's start with the assert function, it is there to test if the input contains 3 numbers exaxtly since that's what the network is accepting in it's shape or else it will raise an error and the program will crash.

From the diagram it seems that you are conserned only about the first output right now and that's the only weights you have, the network in the code is the diagram without the other 2 nodes at the output just the one. by the way this is the simple Perceptron model.
It trying to tell you that later on you can stack many of those mini models to create a bigger model.

The w_sum() method actually just does a weighted sum of your inputs, that's how the simple model works so it does input1 * w1 i+ input2 * w2 + input3 * w3 in this case the w's are the weights of the model and the input's are what is passed in the function

Answer (score 0):

What you have got so far is a very simple neural network, which seems like a good first step to learn more advanced ones. It has no hidden layers and no activation functions. So yes, it doesn't do much at the moment, this is just the base for the upcoming features of the network.

It seems that you understand what the diagram is trying to tell you. There's nothing more to it at the moment than the weighted sum for each output.

The `assert` statement simply checks that the number of inputs correlates with the number of weights. All `w_sum` does is take the sum of every `input` multiplied by it's `weight` and returns it.

Comment: thanks Mandera for that response. Still i am wondering, why i have three times the same output. Do you know what I mean? Like, everyone of the new Neurons (knots) will have the value 0.98 now. Why is that? is it possible, that this Diagram is only a small part of a bigger diagram (with the same code base)?

Comment: Yeah what @Alex_P said. Your `neural_network` function only calculates one output. Confusing indeed